# Mysql joining derived tables

Tags: mysql

This is one where I'm not sure if there is a better approach or not. maybe I just have a syntax error that I'm not seeing. either way here's the issue.

I am trying to get the number of my "friends" (defined by me following them and them following me ,join 1 creating a derived table) that are also following the object I'm looking at in the database. (join 2). this is in a custom function not a stored procedure so I can reuse it in several places. the only pertinant columns are profile_id and follower_profile_id. profile_id is the profile being followed, follower_profile_id is the one doing the following.

here is the query:

```
     set followsThatCorrelate = 
        (
            Select count(id) 
            from 
            ( 
                select * from followers as shouldFollow
                join
                (
                    (select * 
                    from followers 
                    where followers.profile_id = authUserId
                    ) as followingMe 
                    join 
                    (select *
                    from followers 
                    where followers.follower_profile_id = authUserId
                    ) as myFollows 
                    on myFollows.profile_id = followingMe.follower_profile_id
                ) as friends1 
                on shouldFollow.follower_profile_id = friends1.follower_profile_id 
                where shouldFollow.profile_id = otherId
            )
        );
```

it says my syntax error is after I alias the derived table friends. no matter what I put after that it always throws the exception.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE followers (
profile_id NVARCHAR(5),
follower_profile_id NVARCHAR(5)
);

INSERT INTO followers 
VALUES ('Tom','Dick'),('Dick','Tom'),('Carry', 'Tom'),('Tom','Carry'),('John','Tom');

SET @authUserID = 'Tom';

SELECT followsme.follower_profile_id as followerID
FROM followers followsme
-- Join back to the followers table
INNER JOIN followers ifollow
    -- get all of your followers followers
    ON followsme.follower_profile_id = ifollow.profile_id
    -- filter your followers followers to only you.
    AND ifollow.follower_profile_id = @authUserId
-- this restricts the original set to only your followers
WHERE followsme.profile_id = @authUserId
```

Comment: This syntax is completely not compatible for the MySQL platform.

Comment: @kermit - the only incompatible part is where I set up my own test data because the asker didn't supply any.  remove the # from my temp table names the query executes perfectly in mySQL.

Comment: I don't see the value in writing your answer in syntax that's not compatible with the platform the OP is using.

Comment: Fair enough.   Replaced with 100% mysql version.